# How to replace a Pandas .append method in this code

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm working through an IBM course on scraping website and extracting data. In the course they are using the Pandas method .append() which has been discontinued. I've looked through all Pandas documentation and I can't seem to find the way to make this code work without this method. How would you change the code?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')

netflix_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date","Open","High","Low","Close", "Volume"])

for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    date = col[0].text
    open = col[1].text
    high = col[2].text
    low = col[3].text
    close = col[4].text
    adj_close = col[5].text
    volume = col[6].text

    netflix_data = netflix_data.append({"Date":date, "Open":open, "High":high, "Low":low,   "Close":close, "Adj Close":adj_close, "Volume":volume}, ignore_index=True)
```

Merge data scraped and searched using Beautiful Soup into a DataFrame.

Comment: [scrapping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrap#Verb) != [scraping](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrape#Verb)